# QGIS does not recognize the CRS when the data is provided by SQLServer Database with Esri SDE

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

We have a MS SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 database with SDE from Esri on Windows Server 2012 R2. Loading data into QGIS results in the QGIS unkown CRS dialog. If we don't select one CRS the layer is displayed with the questionmark for the unknown CRS. But in the layer properties the correct CRS is displayed anyway (QGIS: Version 3.12.2 and 3.16). Does someone knows a solution or workaround?

[image]

and

[image]